# How can I make a custom sensor in Blender Game Engine 2.79b?

Tags: game-engine

I need to replace a mouse sensor in my control dictionary with a different class that would serve as a sensor that is not provided by default by the Blender version I am using.

Comment: Didn't you ask this yesterday?

Comment: Yes but no one answered so I thought I should rephrase my question.

Comment: In future, if you need to rephrase the question you should use the [edit] link, which will in turn push the question up the 'active' list on the homepage, instead of deleting and re-asking.

Comment: Okay, I understand, my apologies.  I am relatively new to this forum.  At any rate, do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: You may want to familiarise yourself with the site by taking the [Tour]. If someone has an answer they will post it in the answer box below.